# Python findall doesn't return results even on a supposed proper match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, findall

I am trying to filter out just links from an input that the user provides. However currently I am having trouble with Python's findall as it does not return any results.

There might be a mistake in the regular expression itself since that's not a part of my actual code and I copied that in another post but I tried to check it with my current understanding of regular expressions and didn't see an obvious issue.

These are the example links that I am trying to filter :

https://ncs.io/symbolism, https://soundcloud.com/nocopyrightsounds/electro-light-symbolism-ncs-release, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__CRWE-L45k, https://www.deezer.com/track/93333734?app_id=140685, https://open.spotify.com/album/1BxVIZuG2N1ReBB0T5nVTr?highlight=spotify:track:2zVJlAEB0ublkqJMIn43AE

To get the results I am using a simple function which should directly return the result :

```
def get_urls():
    # Gets urls from the provided string
    urls = input("Stream urls: ")
    urls = findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', urls)
    return urls
```

Which I then properly call :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_urls())
```

I am importing just findall from re since that's the only part I use :

```
from re import findall
```

There isn't really much that can break in this small code and I myself am extremely confused as to where I screwed up. If you see me mistake please help me out! Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Works fine for me: `re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', 'http://hello https://hithere')` produces `['http://hello', 'https://hithere']`. Also note, `[^\s]` is just `\S`.

Comment: I edited the post and added the supposedly not matching links.

Could you try running it with the following links? :

https://ncs.io/symbolism, https://soundcloud.com/nocopyrightsounds/electro-light-symbolism-ncs-release, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__CRWE-L45k, https://www.deezer.com/track/93333734?app_id=140685, https://open.spotify.com/album/1BxVIZuG2N1ReBB0T5nVTr?highlight=spotify:track:2zVJlAEB0ublkqJMIn43AE

Comment: Yep, that works as expected too (commas included).

Comment: if you want to exclude comma from URLs then the regexp should be `urls = findall(r'(https?://[^\s,]+)', urls)` . Notice the comma after `\s`

Comment: Is the example input highly contrived? You could just split that input on `,` or `. ` to get a list of the URLs.

Comment: Man I had no idea one could exclude directly in findall. Thanks for letting me know the code runs just fine. If you want points post this as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks again!

Comment: mhawke yeah I want to be prepared for a scenario where a user copies the input from somewhere and it contains like an invalid word or something I want the findall to just list the actual links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me

```
from re import findall

def get_urls():
    # Gets urls from the provided string
    urls = input("Stream urls: ")
    urls = findall(r'(https?://[^\s,]+)', urls)
    return urls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_urls())
```